# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined datatables

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I want to implement datatables but i am getting the following error:

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at jquery.dataTables.min.js:48
at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
var oTable2 = $('#MyDataTable2').show().DataTable({
  "ajax": {
      "url": 'http://mvc/ComplaintHandlerSquadFind',                         
      "type": "GET",
      "dataSrc": "Members",
      "data": { Code : $('#input_1').val() }
  },
  "columns": [
      {"data": "Code"},
      { "data": "Name" },
      { "data": "Email" }
          ]
})
```

This is the JSON getting loaded into the datatable:

```
[{"Members":[{"Code":"001","Name":"Bay","Email":"d1@d.com"},{"Code":"00458","Name":"Beng","Email":"d2@d.com"}]}]
```

Comment: You are attempting to access the `length` property of something. This is not shown in the snippet you have given, please provide all your code

Comment: @wmash you are thinking wrong  all need for solutions writed but you dont even look give negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this means that jQuery DataTables cannot find the data in the response to the Ajax request, see [TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) for more information.

Use the following value for `ajax.dataSrc` option:

```
"dataSrc": "0.Members"
```